# Symfony2 Database Translation Loader isn't executed

Tags: symfony, translation, loader

I have to implement my own translation loader. I've used the tutorial on:
http://blog.elendev.com/development/php/symfony/use-a-database-as-translation-provider-in-symfony-2/
to implement my own translation loader.

I don't get any error's by my code, but the load function of my Loader never gets executed.

Is there any way to tell symfony which translation should be executed?

**config.yml**

```
    translation.loader.db:
    class: Mysk\TranslationBundle\Services\DBLoader
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: translation.loader, alias: db}
```

**DBLoader.php**

```
class DBLoader implements LoaderInterface {

private $transaltionRepository;
private $languageRepository;

/**
 * @param EntityManager $entityManager
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
    $this->transaltionRepository = $entityManager->getRepository("MyskTranslationBundle:LanguageTranslation");
    $this->languageRepository = $entityManager->getRepository("MyskTranslationBundle:Language");
    echo "yeah";
}

function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages'){
    die();
    //Load on the db for the specified local
    $language = $this->languageRepository->getLanguage($locale);
    $translations = $this->transaltionRepository->getTranslations($language, $domain);
    $catalogue = new MessageCatalogue($locale);

    foreach($translations as $translation){
        $catalogue->set($translation->getLanguageToken()->getToken(), $translation->getTranslation(), $domain);
    }

    return $catalogue;
}}
```

Any ideas?

Cheers
Timo

Comment: Did you do the last step? I mean the one about "Create fake translation files". It says that symfony doesn't trigger a loader if there isn't any file in the translations folder.

Comment: Wow, that fixed my problem. Strange behavior of symfony. In this case it's not possible to manage the languages only in the database! 
There will be always someone who have to ad a fake translation file for a new language!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aldo answered this already but just to make it an official answer and to help others:

### You need to create a "fake" translation file to trigger your loader

From [Symfony Dependency Injection Tags: "translation.loader"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#translation-loader)

> [...] If you're loading translations from a database, you'll still need a resource file, but it might either be blank or contain a little bit of information about loading those resources from the database. The file is key to trigger the load method on your custom loader.

So you need to crate files of the form `<domain>.<locale>.<loader-alias>` in your translations folder `app/Resources/translations/`.

In your case one file would be `app/Resources/translations/messages.en.db` for English.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.elendev.com/page/3/#post-26 or http://blog.elendev.com/development/php/symfony/use-a-database-as-translation-provider-in-symfony-2/
Another issue here is that there are no LanguageRepository class in the example. You can use this example.

```
<?php
namespace TranslationBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class LanguageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getLanguage($locale)
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(array('locale' => $locale));
    }
}
```