# How to load translations from a database in Symfony4?

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation

According to [this symfony documentation article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/custom_formats.html#creating-a-custom-loader) it should be possible to load your own translations format. So I'm trying to load them from the database.

But whatever I try to make this work. It just doesn't.

Is using a Database Loader the right way to go or should I do something else to load translations from the database?

**App\Translation\Loader\DatabaseLoader.php:**

```
namespace App\Translation\Loader;

use App\Entity\Translation;
use App\Domain\TranslationManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue;

/**
 * Database Loader
 */
class DatabaseLoader implements LoaderInterface
{
    /**
     * Translation Manager
     *
     * @var TranslationManagerInterface
     */
    private $_translationManager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param TranslationManagerInterface $translationManager
     */
    public function __construct(TranslationManagerInterface $translationManager)
    {
        $this->_translationManager = $translationManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'general')
    {
        $translations = $this->_translationManager->findByLocaleAndDomain($locale, $domain);

        $catalogue = new MessageCatalogue($locale);

        /* @var Translation $translation */
        foreach($translations as $translation)
        {
            $catalogue->set(
                $translation->getToken(),
                $translation->getContent(),
                $translation->getDomain()()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**config/services.yaml:**

```
# database loader
    translation.loader.database:
        class: 'App\Translation\Loader\DatabaseLoader'
        arguments: [ 'App\Domain\TranslationManager' ]
        tags:
            - { name: translation.loader, alias: database, priority: 100 }
```

I've even tried manually adding the the loader to the translator with a event listener on the kernel request. I don't want to use a full bundle as I already a database filled with translations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Database Translation Loader isn't executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350866/symfony2-database-translation-loader-isnt-executed)

Comment: there is a distinction between symfony2 and symfony4

Comment: Which one in this case? Please click the link before replying. ;)

Comment: ther has to be a file in your translations folder {domain}.{locale}.{alias}
Symfony is looking for such a file even if your translations are loaded from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I extended the Translator class to avoid having to create a dummy translation file for every domain in the app.

To override the standard Translator component a Compiler Pass needs to be loaded.

**Translator Compiler Pass:**

```
namespace App\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use App\Domain\TranslationManagerInterface;
use App\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class TranslatorCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    private $translatorServiceId;
    private $readerServiceId;
    private $loaderTag;
    private $debugCommandServiceId;
    private $updateCommandServiceId;

    /**
     * @param string $translatorServiceId
     * @param string $readerServiceId
     * @param string $loaderTag
     * @param string $debugCommandServiceId
     * @param string $updateCommandServiceId
     */
    public function __construct(
        string $translatorServiceId = 'translator.default',
        string $readerServiceId = 'translation.reader',
        string $loaderTag = 'translation.loader',
        string $debugCommandServiceId = 'console.command.translation_debug',
        string $updateCommandServiceId = 'console.command.translation_update'
    ) {
        $this->translatorServiceId = $translatorServiceId;
        $this->readerServiceId = $readerServiceId;
        $this->loaderTag = $loaderTag;
        $this->debugCommandServiceId = $debugCommandServiceId;
        $this->updateCommandServiceId = $updateCommandServiceId;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loaders = [];
        $loaderRefs = [];
        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds($this->loaderTag, true) as $id => $attributes) {
            $loaderRefs[$id] = new Reference($id);
            $loaders[$id][] = $attributes[0]['alias'];
            if (isset($attributes[0]['legacy-alias'])) {
                $loaders[$id][] = $attributes[0]['legacy-alias'];
            }
        }

        if ($container->hasDefinition($this->readerServiceId)) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition($this->readerServiceId);
            foreach ($loaders as $id => $formats) {
                foreach ($formats as $format) {
                    $definition->addMethodCall('addLoader', [$format, $loaderRefs[$id]]);
                }
            }
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition($this->translatorServiceId);

        $definition
            ->setClass(Translator::class)
            ->replaceArgument(0, null)
            ->replaceArgument(1, $definition->getArgument(1))
            ->replaceArgument(2, $definition->getArgument(4)["cache_dir"])
            ->replaceArgument(3, $definition->getArgument(4)["debug"])
            ->replaceArgument(4, $definition->getArgument(4)["resource_files"])
            ->addMethodCall("setTranslationManager", [new Reference(TranslationManagerInterface::class)])
        ;


        if (!$container->hasParameter('twig.default_path')) {
            return;
        }

        if ($container->hasDefinition($this->debugCommandServiceId)) {
            $container->getDefinition($this->debugCommandServiceId)->replaceArgument(4, $container->getParameter('twig.default_path'));
        }

        if ($container->hasDefinition($this->updateCommandServiceId)) {
            $container->getDefinition($this->updateCommandServiceId)->replaceArgument(5, $container->getParameter('twig.default_path'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Translator class:**

```
namespace App\Translation;

use App\Domain\TranslationManagerInterface;
use App\Entity\Model\Translation\Translation;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator as SymfonyTranslator;

class Translator extends SymfonyTranslator
{
    /**
     * @var TranslationManagerInterface
     */
    private $_translationManager;

    /**
     * @param TranslationManagerInterface $translationManager
     */
    public function setTranslationManager(TranslationManagerInterface $translationManager)
    {
        $this->_translationManager = $translationManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function trans($id, array $parameters = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        if (null === $locale && null !== $this->getLocale()) {
            $locale = $this->getLocale();
        }

        if (null === $locale) {
            $locale = $this->getFallbackLocales()[0]; // fallback locale
        }

        // the translation manager automagically creates new translation entries if it doesn't exist yet
        $translation = $this->_translationManager->findOneByTokenLocaleAndDomain($id, $locale, $domain);

        // check if it exists
        if (isset($translation) && null !== $translation && $translation instanceof Translation) {
            return strtr($translation->getContent(), $parameters);
        }

        // fallback
        return parent::trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Tested with Symfony 4.2.4**:
*Maybe this answer comes a little late, but I wanted to help other visitors with same problem who were as desperate as I was.*

1. There is a small error in your class DatabaseLoader. You must **return $catalogue** in function load().

   ```
   public function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'general')
   {
       $translations = $this->_translationManager->findByLocaleAndDomain($locale, $domain);

       $catalogue = new MessageCatalogue($locale);

       /* @var Translation $translation */
       foreach($translations as $translation)
       {
           $catalogue->set(
               $translation->getToken(),
               $translation->getContent(),
               $translation->getDomain()()
           );
       }

       // you must return $catalogue here
       return $catalogue;
   }
   ```
2. You must create "fake" translation files to trigger your loader. See here:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/33300593/6709953

   Example: For translation domain "messages" and locale "en" there must be an empty file **translations/messages.en.database**

   (Small hint: in config/services.yaml you set "alias: database", this means the suffix of the translation file must be .database)
3. You must remove old competing translation files if they exist in folder **translation/**. So for example if there is also file **translations/messages.en.yaml** you must delete it.