# How to properly manage Symfony translations from database

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am actually working on a Symfony 4.4 project, on which I need to be able to update Twig template translations from an admin interface.

This is the first time I try to implement a database based translation system, so I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@andrew72ru/store-translation-messages-in-database-in-symfony-3f12e579df74

At this time, I made a simple class which loads a `MessageCatalogue` from my database:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\Translation;
use App\Repository\TranslationRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue;

class DatabaseTranslationManager implements LoaderInterface
{    
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $doctrine;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed  $resource
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $domain
     */
    public function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages'): MessageCatalogue
    {
        $translationRepository = $this->getRepository();
        if (false === $translationRepository instanceof TranslationRepository) {
            return new MessageCatalogue($locale);
        }
        $messages = $translationRepository->findByDomainAndLocale($domain, $locale);
        $values = array_map(
            static function (Translation $entity) {
                return $entity->getTranslation();
            },
            $messages
        );

        return new MessageCatalogue(
            $locale, [
                $domain => $values,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return ObjectRepository<Translation>
     */
    public function getRepository(): ObjectRepository
    {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository(Translation::class);
    }
}
```

Which is registered in my services:

```
translation.loader.db:
    class: App\Service\DatabaseTranslationManager
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
    tags:
        - { name: translation.loader, alias: db }
```

The associated `Translation` entity is quite straightforward:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TranslationRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TranslationRepository::class)
 */
class Translation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private string $domain;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2)
     */
    private string $locale;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private string $key;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private string $translation;

    public function __construct(string $domain, string $locale, string $key, string $translation)
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
        $this->locale = $locale;
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->translation = $translation;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDomain(): string
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    public function setDomain(string $domain): self
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocale(): string
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    public function setLocale(string $locale): self
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getKey(): string
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    public function setKey(string $key): self
    {
        $this->key = $key;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTranslation(): string
    {
        return $this->translation;
    }

    public function setTranslation(string $translation): self
    {
        $this->translation = $translation;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

It works quite well at this point, but I'm still facing some issues:

- I need to create empty `<domain>.<locale>.db` files so that the custom translation loader is triggered, which is ok but not ideal
- it looks like I need to clear the Symfony cache each time I change a translation in the database. This is an issue as I need translations to be updated anytime by admin users with no access to the console
- I will lose all my translations each time I reset the database. The best option for me would be to load my `<domain>.<locale>.yaml` files as a fallback if a translation does not exist in the database.

As I could not find any better solution at this time, I'm looking for recommendations on how to achieve such a translation system.

Comment: There's really no way to answer, since there are many approaches. instead of the `EntityManagerInterface` inject the repo as a service . `__construct(TranslationRepository $repo)`.  Yes anytime the translations are updated in prod or a new translation is added in either dev or prod the Symfony cache needs to be refreshed, you can [manually call and execute `Command` from a controller or service](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/console/command_in_controller.html). Otherwise you can use the [Messenger component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) to queue the job.

Comment: Can you clarify "*I will lose all my translations each time I reset the database*"? Why would the database be reset or what is causing the reset? Are you referring to needing something like [migrations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)?

Comment: Also, it appears someone else has asked a very similar question [How to load translations from a database in Symfony4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50117878/1144627) that may be of some help.

Comment: @WillB. thanks for your answer! I also thought of using a command but I will take a look at the Messenger component to achieve this.
"I will lose all my translations each time I reset the database": of course it should not happen in a production environment, but when working locally I would like to use the "default" translation files (like messages.en.yaml for example) as a fallback if a translation key does not exist in the database