# Is there a way to replace the trans tag behaviour?

Tags: twig, translate, symfony5

So, I have this:
A fully grown symfony5 project which uses **{% trans %}** in every template, and this gets the translated messages from **/translations/messages.es.yml**

The thing is we want to get that translations from a certain database table, which has an id, original value, translated value, locale, company id.
So, depending on the company selected by the user, it should gather the translations from certain rows only.
And the important part of all of it is it should work with the current **trans** tags so this way we would not be forced to change every template.

Is there a way for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load translations from a database in Symfony4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117878/how-to-load-translations-from-a-database-in-symfony4)

Comment: I tried that but I can't manage to pass the arguments from the service to the DatabaseLoader. Also, I don't understand how does this access to the Translation Entity